# How to extract data from a specfic section of a wikipedia page using Wikipedia API?

Tags: android, json, mediawiki-api

I want to extrect the Nutrients section of a vegetable/fruit from the wikipedia and want to show it in my android app.

[image: I am taking about the table in the right hand side of the picture]

This is what i have got so far..

To extract the Nutrients section of the "[Banana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banana)"

https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=parse&page=banana&prop=wikitext&section=23&format=json

But i don't know how to filter out this table(the table in the right hand side of the above picture) from the data i have got from the above link. Is it something that i have to figure out in my codes when parsing this data or i have to do something with the url?

Can anyone help me to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, you'll have to do that yourself. You can use https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/mobile-sections/Banana which is a little easier to use (OTOH it's more internally focused and so less stable) and does remove certain parts of the HTML, but you'd still have to deal with the table. Or you can try https://en.wikipedia.org/api/rest_v1/page/html/Banana which uses the next-generation HTML renderer and has more metadata in the HTML so it's maybe easier to transform, but you'd still have to do the transformation yourself.